# Shortcut for checking current_user.logged_in? as false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know if there is a shortcut to things being false like there is for things being true e.g.

```
current_user.logged_in == 'true'
```

is equal to

```
current_user.logged_in?
```

from memory there is the not operator '!' but im not sure how it would work. Do these equate to be the same?

```
current_user.logged_in? == 'false'
```

and

```
!current_user.logged_in?
```

I know I can use current_user.nil? to see if they are logged out but i want to know for other methods as well e.g.

```
current_user.mod_of_game? @guide
```

returns true of the are a mod but is there  shortcut for:

```
if (current_user.mod_of_game? @guide) == 'false'
```

Still learning the ins and outs of rails and cant really find a good answer on a shortcut for false.

Thanks

Comment: `current_user.logged_in? == 'false'` probably doesn't do what you think it does. You're comparing a boolean to a string which will always evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby the '?' character does not mean anything special at the end of a method name, it's just a valid last character of the name. It is convention to use it at the end of methods returning boolean values. So you know that `.logged_in?` will return `true` or `false`.

The '!' character is the logical negation, so `true == !false`. In this case, `!user.logged_in?` literally means "NOT `user.logged_in?`", so if the user is not logged in, the overall statement will be true. The behavior of '!' is the same in most programming languages by the way.

As a side note, `current_user.logged_in?` is not good, because if nobody is logged in you will get an exception: `current_user` would be `nil`, and `nil` does not have a method called `.logged_in?`. The correct way is to use `current_user.nil?` and `!current_user.nil?` as you point out.

The shortcut for `if (current_user.mod_of_game? @guide) == false` would be `if !current_user.mod_of_game?(@guide)`. This assuming that your `.mod_of_game?` method has one argument.

Comment: Thanks! I did notice using `current_user.logged_in?` just throws a no method error for non logged in users. It also throws a no method error for current_user.mod_of_game? do i have to put all current_user methods that require the user to be logged_in inside an if else statement (using current_user.nil?) or is there an easier way. (Sorry just a quick question while its on topic, don't want to open another question topic for it.)

Comment: In general you would add a `before_action` filter in the controller, which will check whether a user is logged in. If you are using devise, that would be `before_action :authenticate_user!`. You can add a `only: [:action1, :action2, …]` if you need authentication only for some actions and not others.

Comment: Thanks i ended up asking the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714097/shortcut-for-checking-current-user-logged-in-as-false/34714318#34714318

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your original statements probably doesn't do what you want.

```
current_user.logged_in? == 'false'
```

Here, `logged_in?` likely returns a boolean (I'm assuming since it makes poor design otherwise) and you're comparing it to `'false'` which is a string. This means it will always evaluate to `false`. You probably meant the following:

```
current_user.logged_in? == false
```

In which case, the following statements are completely equivalent:

```
current_user.logged_in? == false
!current_user.logged_in?
```

The `!` operator means 'not' so it inverts the value of the proceeding expression (where it's a boolean).

Following that, your last expression can be simplified to:

```
if !(current_user.mod_of_game? @guide)
```

since it takes the value of the method call `mod_of_game?` and inverts it.